# Повторная ошибка запроса

Tags: mysqli, php, mysql

**Здравствуйте! Извините за повторный аналогичный вопрос, но не могу справиться с ним. Вот:**

```
$connection = @mysqli_connect(HOST, USER, PASS, DB) or die("Нет соединения с БД");
mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8") or die("Не установлена кодировка соединения");

function eyestopper($eyestopper, $connection){
        $query = "SELECT goods_id, name, img, price FROM goods
                                WHERE visible='1' AND $eyestopper='1'";
        $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error());

        $eyestoppers = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
                $eyestoppers[] = $row;
        }

        return $eyestoppers;
}

$view = empty($_GET['view']) ? 'activ' : $_GET['view'];
$eyestoppers = eyestopper($eyestopper, $connection);
switch($view){
        case('hits'):
                // лидеры продаж
                $eyestoppers = eyestopper('hits', $connection);
        break;

        case('new'):
                // новинки
                $eyestoppers = eyestopper('new', $connection);
        break;

        case('sale'):
                // распродажа
                $eyestoppers = eyestopper('sale', $connection);
        break;

        default:
                // если из адресной строки получено имя несуществующего вида
                $view = 'activ';
                $eyestoppers = eyestopper('activ', $connection);
}
```

**Выходит ошибка:**

```
Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in N:\home\programirovanie.ru\www\model\model.php on line 82
```

82 линия это:

```
$res = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
```

**Как исправить?**

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю решить проблему таким образом:

```
global $connection
$connection = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASS, DB) or die("Нет соединения с БД");
mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8") or die("Не установлена кодировка соединения");

function eyestopper($eyestopper){
        global $connection;
        $query = "SELECT goods_id, name, img, price FROM goods
                                WHERE visible='1' AND $eyestopper='1'";
        $res = $connection->query($query);

        $eyestoppers = array();
        while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
                $eyestoppers[] = $row;
        }

        return $eyestoppers;
}
```

Суть решения такова: избавляемся от параметра второго у функции $connection, вместо этого объявляем глобальную переменную коннекта, собственно через которую и идет подключение к базе. Писал все без проверки на практике, просто по старому опыту, потому могут быть опечатки и неточности. Может быть не самое изящное решение, но тем не менее должно помочь. Тестируйте, проверяйте, если что-то не будет работать, то пишите мне, вместе найдем решение.

Comment: @IntegralAL, к сожалению, не работает(

Comment: VasyOk, слышь! За словами следи ган***!

Comment: Не превращайте форум в базар по понятиям. И матом шпарить тоже не стоит, здесь это не приветствуется.

Comment: @DimasikYES, что именно не работает? Какую ошибку выдает в моем варианте кода? Надеюсь, Вы убрали дальше по коду при вызове функции второй параметр?

Comment: @IntegralAL, Спасибо большое, решил по другому)

Comment: @DimasikYES, не за что. Я обновил код свой, должен работать. По крайней мере у меня работает он, правда, с другой таблицей. Следите за совпадением имен полей у таблицы (указывайте существующие поля), это про первый параметр функции eyestopper. Ошибка из-за этого, а от второго параметра коннекта лучше вовсе избавиться, как я показал на примере.

Comment: @IntegralAL, что интересно, что activ у меня существует, все правильно, проверил.

Comment: @DreamChild, Это ему пишите, а не мне!